# Glass or Mirror API - checking if user is on WiFi before uploading

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Is there a way to determine if the user is on wifi or 3G/4G? (Use case: check before uploading)

Comment: If you're using the Mirror API, the synchronization is handled for you automatically and you shouldn't need to worry about this.  Can you expand on your explanation a bit to explain in what situation you want this?

Answer (score 1):

No, if you're using the Mirror API, connection management is already handled for you. It is not exposed via the API.

You can file a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list). It is helpful to describe a use case.